# Proper way to get a DbContext in a gRPC service implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, grpc

Various examples online show injecting a DbContext into a gRPC service in the service constructor:

```
public ImageStorageService(ILogger<ImageStorageService> logger, SqliteDbContext dbContext)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}
```

and using that _dbContext in all the gRPC implementation methods. This doesn't seem right - I'm new to EF and .Net Core web in general but a DbContext is not thread-safe and multiple gRPC methods can be executing at the same time, yes?

Anyway I found another way, here's the constructor and an example api method implementation:

```
public ImageStorageService(ILogger<ImageStorageService> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
}

public override async Task<GetImageCountReply> GetImageCount(GetImageCountRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SqliteDbContext>();
    var count = await dbContext.StoredImages.CountAsync(context.CancellationToken);
    return new GetImageCountReply { Count = count };
}
```

Am I over-complicating things? services.AddDbContext<> injects database contexts with Scoped lifetime so this is necessary, isn't it?

Comment: I believe that nothing really beats the usual using(SqliteDbContext dbContext = new SqliteDbContext()) form. The reason why I don't inject the DbContext in my own code is because I keep injections reserved for interfaces, not concrete classes (not an absolute rule though). In your example, when you request the DbContext, you indicate the type of DbContext you need, so why would you need the extra gear to instanciate it anyway ? Is it because you are passing parameters to the constructor of the DbContext ?

Comment: Using the simple injector allows the use of built-in features like AddDbContextPool when performance warrants it, as an example. I think using injection is the preferred way.